# Why does jQuery's .not() method remove text nodes?

Tags: jquery

The `.not()` method takes either a [selector or an object](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with which to filter.

The `.contents()` method [returns a jQuery object containing the children](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) **and text nodes** of an element.

When a selector is used as the argument for `.not()` it removes the selected elements but also **all the text nodes**.

When an object is used as the arguement for `.not()` it removes the object but **not** the text nodes.

Example:

```
<p>This is a <span id="aSpan">paragraph</span> tag</p>

$("p").contents().not("span");
> []
```

But!

```
var $sp = $("p span");
$("p").contents().not($sp);
> ["This is a ", " tag"]
```

also

```
var sp = document.getElementById("aSpan");
$("p").contents().not(sp);
> ["This is a ", " tag"]
```

Why are text nodes selected by the "span" selector (or any other selector) but not by an object instance?

Comment: For some reason they added this to [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L260). In case of a string, they first explicitly filter to keep only elements (`nodeType === 1`).

Comment: @pimvdb that's a good find - I wonder what the reasoning for this was...

Comment: @AndyF If you click "Blame" at the top, you'll see what commits were made and why on each line.

Comment: Okay, they seem to have added the filtering [in this revision](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/c85243dfc4b09e6bb87532f2025f686b6ae45a22) (in `core.js`). Looking at [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), I noticed that the jQuery object signature of `.filter`/`.not` was added later on, and apparently they implemented that in a simple-minded way without thinking about text nodes.

Comment: OK, so it looks like maybe it was just an oversight? I guess there's no definitive answer to this question unless we get some "Word of God" reason for why it was done that way. If, for now, anyone wants to formulate these comments as an answer I will be happy to accept. Thank you all for taking the time to look into it!

Comment: jQuery has never handled text nodes well. If you actually need to work with text nodes, I'd avoid jQuery. If you have a concrete problem, then maybe we can help with that.

Comment: You could, of course, file a bug/feature request on http://bugs.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this happens can be traced back to [this particular edit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/87869b8b81380617cfad8788799ee40de0e3e9c4#L0L0), made 3 years ago. It unifies the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) methods, greatly simplifying both since they're effectively each other's opposites.

Before the above edit, `.not()` would have called `.filter()` internally if the selector were anything but a string, so it would have operated on a filtered collection (i.e. `.nodeType === 1`) starting from [this revision](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/c85243dfc4b09e6bb87532f2025f686b6ae45a22) made 4 years ago.

This means that - based on your code example - before the edit `.not(object)` would have returned an empty collection as well, which seems more logical than its current behavior.

Now, both `.not(object)` and `.filter(object)` operate on the unfiltered collection, though only the former method will exhibit the behavioral difference.